# Need a help in fixing the JSON and deserialize

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

I am trying to parse a JSON file which has a space between two strings.

```
{
    "result": {
        "input": {
            "address": {
                "street": "1500 PENNSYLVANIA AVE NW",
                "zip": "20502",
                "city": "WASHINGTON",
                "state": "DC"
            },
            "benchmark": {
                "benchmarkName": "Public_AR_Current",
                "isDefault": false,
                "benchmarkDescription": "Public Address Ranges - Current Benchmark",
                "id": "4"
            },
            "vintage": {
                "isDefault": true,
                "vintageName": "Current_Current",
                "vintageDescription": "Current Vintage - Current Benchmark",
                "id": "4"
            }
        },
        "addressMatches": [{
            "geographies": {
                "114th Congressional Districts": [{
                    "OID": 211904692355590,
                    "MTFCC": "G5200",
                    "FUNCSTAT": "N",
                    "STATE": "11",
                    "AREAWATER": 18633403,
                    "NAME": "Delegate District (at Large)",
                    "CDSESSN": "114",
                    "LSADC": "C4",
                    "CENTLON": "-077.0162745",
                    "GEOID": "1198",
                    "CENTLAT": "+38.9047579",
                    "CD114": "98",
                    "INTPTLON": "-077.0172290",
                    "AREALAND": 158364990,
                    "BASENAME": "Delegate District (at Large)",
                    "INTPTLAT": "+38.9041031",
                    "OBJECTID": 254
                }]
            },
            "matchedAddress": "1500 PENNSYLVANIA AVE NW, WASHINGTON, DC, 20220",
            "coordinates": {
                "x": -77.03376,
                "y": 38.89877
            },
            "addressComponents": {
                "preQualifier": "",
                "preDirection": "",
                "preType": "",
                "streetName": "PENNSYLVANIA",
                "suffixType": "AVE",
                "suffixDirection": "NW",
                "suffixQualifier": "",
                "zip": "20220",
                "city": "WASHINGTON",
                "fromAddress": "1500",
                "toAddress": "1598",
                "state": "DC"
            },
            "tigerLine": {
                "tigerLineId": "76225866",
                "side": "L"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I used JSON2Apex tool to covert this Json to Apex class.

Here is the class file:

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public class Input {
        public Address address;
        public Benchmark benchmark;
        public Vintage vintage;
    }

    public class Address {
        public String street;
        public String zip;
        public String city;
        public String state;
    }

    public Result result;

    public class CongressionalDistricts {
        public Long OID;
        public String MTFCC;
        public String FUNCSTAT;
        public String STATE;
        public Integer AREAWATER;
        public String NAME;
        public String CDSESSN;
        public String LSADC;
        public String CENTLON;
        public String GEOID;
        public String CENTLAT;
        public String CD114;
        public String INTPTLON;
        public Long AREALAND;
        public String BASENAME;
        public String INTPTLAT;
        public Integer OBJECTID;
    }

    public class TigerLine {
        public String tigerLineId;
        public String side;
    }

    public class Coordinates {
        public Double x;
        public Double y;
    }

    public class Benchmark {
        public String benchmarkName;
        public Boolean isDefault;
        public String benchmarkDescription;
        public String id;
    }

    public class AddressComponents {
        public String preQualifier;
        public String preDirection;
        public String preType;
        public String streetName;
        public String suffixType;
        public String suffixDirection;
        public String suffixQualifier;
        public String zip;
        public String city;
        public String fromAddress;
        public String toAddress;
        public String state;
    }

    public class Geographies {
        public List<CongressionalDistricts> CongressionalDistricts;
    }

    public class Vintage {
        public Boolean isDefault;
        public String vintageName;
        public String vintageDescription;
        public String id;
    }

    public class AddressMatches {
        public Geographies geographies;
        public String matchedAddress;
        public Coordinates coordinates;
        public AddressComponents addressComponents;
        public TigerLine tigerLine;
    }

    public class Result {
        public Input input;
        public List<AddressMatches> addressMatches;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

The issue which I am facing is when i try to deserialize this code I am getting Null value in CongressionalDistrict. In my code I am replacing the Json string "114th Congressional District" with CongressionalDistrict . After replacing also I am getting Null value.

Here is the code which I am using.

```
Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();

    String urlAdd = 'https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/address?street=1500+PENNSYLVANIA+AVE+NW&city=WASHINGTON&state=DC&zip=20502&benchmark=4&vintage=4&layers=54&format=json';
    request.setEndpoint(urlAdd);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    response = http.send(request);
    String jString = response.getBody();
    System.debug('** jString *** '+jString);
    jString = jString.replace('114th Congressional Districts', 'CongressionalDistricts:');

    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        JSON2Apex resultJSON2Apex = (JSON2Apex) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), JSON2Apex.class);          
        System.debug('#### resultJSON2Apex ###### '+resultJSON2Apex);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is odd - I have used that technique in the past and it worked. I ran the same code and got the same results, so it is something odd with the parsing I think. As a workaround, yon can use the deserializeUntyped method, and that seems to work for me in so far as I can then see the Congressional District data in the Map:

```
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jString);
```

Actually, I see the issue once I used strict to deserialize - you didn't replace res.getbody() with jstring in the parsing:

```
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        JSON2Apex resultJSON2Apex = (JSON2Apex) JSON.deserialize(**response.getBody()**, JSON2Apex.class);          
        System.debug('#### resultJSON2Apex ###### '+resultJSON2Apex);
    }
```

Comment: Ha. Find and replace...and discard. Nice catch!

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in your code: You are replacing '114th Congressional Districts' with 'CongressionalDistricts:'

You only included the colon in the second String literal, so you will end up with 'CongressionalDistricts::'

Change it to:

```
 jString = jString.replace('114th Congressional Districts', 'CongressionalDistricts');
```

Comment: My mistake i thought I removed ':' from my code. No still I am getting Null value.